# PIL putpixel does nothing

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

At high school, we are beginning with Python and we are asked to program a small image processor using the `Pillow` module. The goal is to open a file, then choose a filter.

The first filter I tried to program is to change the color temperature.
But there's also a minimalist interface with tkinter that shows some buttons and it works without problems.

Here is the function that opens the file

```
def Ouvrir():
    fichier = askopenfilename(title="Ouvrir une image",filetypes=[('jpg files','.jpg'),('all files','.*')])
    global img
    img =Image.open(fichier)
    l, h = img.size
    img.show()   #visualisation de l'image

    global img2
    img2 = img #img2 est une copie de img
```

It creates a global `img` image object that is loaded from the file. Then `l` and `h` are loaded with the width and height of the image.

Another global object image `img2` is created for the output image, and it is a copy of `img`.

Then here is the function that processes the image

```
def filtreTC(): #Filtre permettant de changer la température de couleur
    coef = sliderTC.get() / 100 #On récupère le coefficient à partir de l'échelle. Le coefficient compris entre -1 et 1: -1 = froid (image bleu-vert), 0 = neutre, 1 = chaud (image orangée)
    fenTC.destroy() #On ferme la fenêtre
    if(coef <= 0): #Calcul des coefficients rouges, verte et bleus
        coefR = 1 + coef
        coefV = 1 + (coef / 2)
        coefB = 1
    else:
        coefR = 1
        coefV = 1 - (coef / 2)
        coefB = 1 - coef
    for y in range(0, h, 1):
        for x in range(0, l, 1):
            r, v, b = img.getpixel((x, y))
            r = int(float(r * coefR))
            v = int(float(v * coefV))
            b = int(float(b * coefB))
            img2.putpixel((x, y), (r, v, b))
    img2.show()
```

It's a loop that scans through the whole image and takes a pixel from `img`, multiply its rgb values by their corresponding coefficients, then puts that pixel in `img2`

The problem is that it doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors, but when it shows `img2` it's the same as `img1`, like the `putpixel` function didn't do anything.

I checked a lot of things so I know the problem is neither the rgb values nor the x/y coordinates.

- I tried replacing `img2 = img` by `img2 = Image.new("RGB", (l, h))`and what I get is a black image.
- I then tried replacing `img2.putpixel((x, y), (r, v, b))` by `img2.putpixel((100, 100), (127, 127, 127))` so that way I should get a grey pixel near the top left corner. But I still got a black image.

I then tried to remove

```
global img2
img2 = img
```

from the function that opens a file and put

```
img2 = Image.new("RGB", (l, h))
```

right after `fenTC.destroy()` and I got this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\ISN\Programmes\TP-image\projet.py", line 62, in filtreTC
    img2.show()
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2016, in show
    _show(self, title=title, command=command)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2876, in _show
    _showxv(image, **options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2881, in _showxv
    ImageShow.show(image, title, **options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 51, in show
    if viewer.show(image, title=title, **options):
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 75, in show
    return self.show_image(image, **options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 95, in show_image
    return self.show_file(self.save_image(image), **options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py", line 91, in save_image
    return image._dump(format=self.get_format(image), **self.options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 639, in _dump
    self.save(filename, format, **options)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1969, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py", line 319, in _save
    (rawmode, stride, -1))])
  File "e:\xxxx\programmes\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 512, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Basically a lot of stuff I've got no idea what it means except:

```
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

I checked the x and y coordinates and they never went beyond the borders, so I don't understand what's this error.

I spent several hours to try figure out what the problem was and tried lots of different things but none of them worked. So I thought it was better to ask for help

Comment: Avoid using global variables in your function. It makes it hard or impossible for us to really know what's going on. Instead include a [mcve]. With __all__ the code needed to reproduce your issue. The fact that you get an error saying "tile cannot extend outside image" would indicate that you are making some incorrect assumption about what your image shape is.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you *didn't create a copy*. `img2 = img` creates another reference to the same object, not a new, separate image.

To create a actual copy, use the [`image.copy()` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy):

```
img2 = img.copy()
```

Next, I'd not use a loop and `getpixel()` / `putpixel()` combinations. You are doing double work for RGB values that appear more than once. If you use the `image.point()` method then you get to use your formula on each *unique value in each band* in the image, and leave the looping over all pixels to the library (much faster). It also makes the image copy for you!

You need to create a table; for values 0 through 255 for the R, G and B values, calculate the possible result, and put those 3 * 256 results in a long list:

```
coefG = [i * (1 - (coef / 2)) for i in range(256)]
if coef <= 0:
    coefR = [i * (1 + coef) for i in range(256)]
    coefB = list(range(256))
else:
    coefR = list(range(256))
    coefB = [i * (1 - coef) for i in range(256)]
img2 = img1.point(coefR + coefG + coefB)
```

The resulting table is used for each unique color value in the image.

You could also split the RGB image into separate bands, apply your different coefficient formulas to each separate band as a function then re-combine the bands into a new image:

```
r, g, b = img.split()
g = g.point(lambda i: i * (1 - (coef / 2)))
if coef <= 0:
    r = r.point(lambda i: i * (1 + coef))
else:
    b = b.point(lambda i: i * (1 - coef))
img = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
```

When creating an image filter, you'd really want to pass in the input image as a *function argument* rather than use globals. Pass in the coefficient as well:

```
def filtreTC(source_image, coef):
    coefG = [i * (1 - (coef / 2)) for i in range(256)]
    if coef <= 0:
        coefR = [i * (1 + coef) for i in range(256)]
        coefB = list(range(256))
    else:
        coefR = list(range(256))
        coefB = [i * (1 - coef) for i in range(256)]
    return source_image.point(coefR + coefG + coefB)
```

You can then store the result of the call in a global if you must, but the function can now stand on its own, and can be re-used anywhere that has a RGB PIL image object. You'd call the function with the slider value:

```
coef = sliderTC.get() / 100
fenTC.destroy()
img2 = filtreTC(img, coef)
```

Using the above on your profile image

[image: question-asker profile image, a chip]

with a coefficient of 0.75, gives us:

[image: same profile image, but turned orange]

while -0.75 results in:

[image: same profile image, but now blue]

Comment: Thank you. I understand that using getpixel/putpixel is obviously not a proper method. The teacher told us that the PIL library does indeed have methods for image processing. But he told us to use getpixel/putpixel so that we understand how image processing works. If I use your `filtreTC` function it works perfectly. I 
 then modified my `filtreTC` function so that it takes a source image and an argument, time again no error but I get a black image, like if the putpixel function didn't do anything. But surprisingly Image.point works and I don't understand why.

Comment: @IntegratedElectronics: your loop code worked fine for me when I tried it with `img2 = img.copy()`, for what it is worth. Put the copy at the top of the function, run your loop over the `img.size` dimensions, and return the altered copy.